# Anybody familiar with api's know what is going on (ErgastAPI for F1 data)?

Tags: typescript, api

In my program, I am trying to make it easier to fetch data from ergast (an api with hold f1 data). I essentially created a wrapper, but when I run my premade test script, I have an error which I don't fully understand

Link to code: https://github.com/ultimatehecker/Formula-One-Wrapper
Error:

```
      2 |
      3 |     responseWithoutRaces(callResponse: any) {
    > 4 |         return callResponse["MRData"]["RaceTable"]["Races"].length === 0;
        |                                      ^
      5 |     }
      6 |
      7 |     responseWithoutCircuits(callResponse: any) {

      TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RaceTable')
      at ResponsesValidator.responseWithoutRaces (src/client/responsesValidator.ts:4:38)
      at src/client/races.ts:20:41
      at src/utils/request.ts:10:13
```

I know the error has to do with `MRData` ebing undefined, but I dont really know why

Im not too familiar with API development, let alone Typescript itself (trying to not use Javascript), so any help would be appreciative

I have tried logging callResposne, which returns data:

console.log

```
  {
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: AxiosHeaders {
        date: 'Sat, 08 Apr 2023 13:13:36 GMT',
        server: 'Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16',
        'x-powered-by': 'PHP/5.4.16',
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
        'cache-control': 'public, max-age=300',
        'content-length': '607',
        connection: 'close',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      },
      config: {
        transitional: {
          silentJSONParsing: true,
          forcedJSONParsing: true,
          clarifyTimeoutError: false
        },
        adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
        transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
        transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
        timeout: 0,
        xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
        xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
        maxContentLength: -1,
        maxBodyLength: -1,
        env: { FormData: [Function], Blob: [class Blob] },
        validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
        headers: AxiosHeaders {
          Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'User-Agent': 'axios/1.3.4',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
        },
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/4.json?offset=0&limit=200',
        data: undefined
      },
      request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          abort: [Function (anonymous)],
          aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
          connect: [Function (anonymous)],
          error: [Function (anonymous)],
          socket: [Function (anonymous)],
          timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
          finish: [Function: requestOnFinish]
        },
        _eventsCount: 7,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        outputData: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        destroyed: false,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
        _defaultKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        strictContentLength: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        _closed: false,
        socket: Socket {
          connecting: false,
          _hadError: false,
          _parent: null,
          _host: 'ergast.com',
          _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 7,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          allowHalfOpen: false,
          _sockname: null,
          _pendingData: null,
          _pendingEncoding: '',
          server: null,
          _server: null,
          parser: null,
          _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
          [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 1083,
          [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
          [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
          [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
          [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
          [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: true,
          [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 60,
          [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
          [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
        },
        _header: 'GET /api/f1/2014/4.json?offset=0&limit=200 HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
          'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
          'User-Agent: axios/1.3.4\r\n' +
          'Accept-Encoding: gzip, compress, deflate, br\r\n' +
          'Host: ergast.com\r\n' +
          'Connection: close\r\n' +
          '\r\n',
        _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
        _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
        agent: Agent {
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 2,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          defaultPort: 80,
          protocol: 'http:',
          options: [Object: null prototype],
          requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
          sockets: [Object: null prototype],
          freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
          keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
          keepAlive: false,
          maxSockets: Infinity,
          maxFreeSockets: 256,
          scheduling: 'lifo',
          maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
          totalSocketCount: 1,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        socketPath: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
        path: '/api/f1/2014/4.json?offset=0&limit=200',
        _ended: true,
        res: IncomingMessage {
          _readableState: [ReadableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 4,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          socket: [Socket],
          httpVersionMajor: 1,
          httpVersionMinor: 1,
          httpVersion: '1.1',
          complete: true,
          rawHeaders: [Array],
          rawTrailers: [],
          joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
          aborted: false,
          upgrade: false,
          url: '',
          method: null,
          statusCode: 200,
          statusMessage: 'OK',
          client: [Socket],
          _consuming: false,
          _dumped: false,
          req: [Circular *1],
          responseUrl: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/4.json?offset=0&limit=200',
          redirects: [],
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
          [Symbol(kHeaders)]: [Object],
          [Symbol(kHeadersCount)]: 16,
          [Symbol(kTrailers)]: null,
          [Symbol(kTrailersCount)]: 0
        },
        aborted: false,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        reusedSocket: false,
        host: 'ergast.com',
        protocol: 'http:',
        _redirectable: Writable {
          _writableState: [WritableState],
          _events: [Object: null prototype],
          _eventsCount: 3,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _options: [Object],
          _ended: true,
          _ending: true,
          _redirectCount: 0,
          _redirects: [],
          _requestBodyLength: 0,
          _requestBodyBuffers: [],
          _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
          _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
          _currentUrl: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/4.json?offset=0&limit=200',
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        },
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kEndCalled)]: true,
        [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
        [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
        [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
          accept: [Array],
          'user-agent': [Array],
          'accept-encoding': [Array],
          host: [Array]
        },
        [Symbol(errored)]: null,
        [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
      },
      data: {
        MRData: {
          xmlns: 'http://ergast.com/mrd/1.5',
          series: 'f1',
          url: 'http://ergast.com/api/f1/2014/4.json',
          limit: '200',
          offset: '0',
          total: '1',
          RaceTable: [Object]
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried increasing jest timeout, which did nothing and also ran into the issue of the tests passing in unusually fast times (1 to 5ms).

Comment: Console log the value of `callResponse`

Comment: Edited the question to have that data, I have looked at this before and it has a field for MRData

Comment: Looks like `callResponse` is the request/response, so you need to access the `data` property first: `callResponse.data.MRData.RaceTable.Races.length`

Comment: So in `races.ts` would I have to move this:

`callback(null, new Race(response["MRData"]["RaceTable"]["Races"][0]));`
to this:
`callback(null, new Race(response.data.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0]))`